# Scanning online URL for images

Tags: url, web

There is a web page *www.somepage.com/images/*

I know some of the images there (e.g. *www.somepage.com/images/cat_523.jpg*, *www.somepage.com/images/dog_179.jpg*)

I know there are some more but I don't know the names of those photos. How can I scan whole */images/* folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use wget to download all the files

--no-parent to grab all the files below in the directory hierachy

--recursive to look into subfolders

```js
wget --recursive --no-parent -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the webpage as an img tag you could try just searching the page source for an img tag. If you are using terminal you could also try using a tool such as wget to download the web page and then try using grep on the file for the img tag.